# WP функция the_permalink() не выводит категорию

Tags: wordpress

В настройках wp вывод поста стоит `/%category%/%postname%.html`

Используя функцию the_permalink или get_permalink я получаю ссылка на пост без учета рубрики. 
При этом если авторизироваться в админке и зайти на сайт то функции выдают ссылку с учетом рубрики.

Функции использую внутри цикла код ниже

```
       $posts = get_posts(array(
            'numberposts' => 15,
            'category' => 5,
            'orderby' => 'post_date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'exclude' => '5300',
        ));
         foreach ($posts as $post) {
            setup_postdata($post);
            the_permalink();
         }
```

Comment: Рассказ занимательный. Вопрос  где?

Comment: @SeVlad Как видно из кода внутри цикла foreach. На главной странице. Если смотреть авторизированно, то ссылки имеют вид site.by/category/post 
Если в режиме инкогнито(не авторизированно) то site.by/post